# “Over” meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

“Texas  Constitutional Convention of 1869 dissolved over factional differences without drafting a final document.”
Wound anybody help me explain the “over” used in the sentence? And the meaning of the whole sentence.? 
Because I known that the “over” word has many different meanings, so an example with each meaning will be a pleased for me as well. Thanks

Comment: Did you look up a dictionary? The basic interpretation is prepositinal "in", "with", or "of", and it is conjunctive like "because of", "while" or "after". "Texas ... dissolved ... had factional differences ... did not proceed to draft a final document." The basic reason to use *over* is lexical. It is often used like "talk about". There is a distancing (ablative) aspect.

Comment: I did look up a dictionary already but not sure about the meaning used in this sentence. Would you mind explaining a little deeper. Or another word synonym that I could use to replace “over”. And I still aint understand the meaning of sentence which you just explained above. Thanks for spending time with me.

Comment: *TCC had factional differences. TCC dissolved. TCC has not drafted a final document.* Better? The last phrase is difficult to rephrase without loss of meaning, because it's em edded deeply in the sentence structure.

Answer (score 1):

yes, as you mentioned the `over` has several meaning, I give you some example for each application:

> 1- he put his hand over his mouth
>   2- he climbs over a wall
>   3-1 the discussion was running **over (during)** dinner # this usage is the same usage of your sentence
>   3-2 he slept **over (during)** his work 
>   4-they rule over a land
>   5- over the past ten years
>   6- over the whole city
>   7- five hours or over / over ten thousand people
>   8- I heard it over the radio
>   9- there is any food left over

then your sentence would be like :

> Texas Constitutional Convention of 1869 dissolved **over/during** factional differences without drafting a final document

Comment: OH dear, your explaination is really clear. That’s exact why I’ve been confused so far. Really appreciate.